# How to opmize to load of sources or assets in aframe?

Tags: local-storage, indexeddb, aframe, webvr

Currently I have several resources with too much weight (MB), for which the rendering of the application is slow, Is there any way to optimize that?;
I was thinking to use store in web-browser with indexeedDB or another similar technologie.

Do you think that some storage technology in the web browser, allows to optimize the load of resources?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: See links in [this thread](https://discourse.threejs.org/t/how-to-optimize-objects-in-three-js-methods-of-optimization/2242/4) for general tips about performance in three.js, which also apply to A-Frame. As it is, this question is too broad for Stack Overflow. You also need to clarify whether the page is taking a long time to load, has a low framerate once it does load, or both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. To get started, I don't have devices for VR such as VIVE, daydream, etc. 
I have a web server installed on my PC. When I render a scene with characters on the PC with the address 192.168.100.34/aframe/example1.html (or localhost) there is no problem, the loading time is fast and optimal. The problem is when I try to access that URL from my mobile device, the loading time is slow, the same happens with the resources of 360 images, the buffering of a video, etc. Any suggestions?